# s3 write speed is too slow - is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

We are moving from NFS to S3 but I am not happy with the write performance.

How can I speed it up ? Are there any configurations to use while moving large files?

Now it's around ~10MB/s vs our regular NFS filesystem 200MB/s ie 20 times slower.

I am curious about the general write performance you guys see on your system.

My observations using s3cmd version 2.1.0:

**Put a 4gb tar file on s3 storage shows 8.45 MB/s**

upload: '' -> 's3://yetest/backups/si106-251/si106-251.20221219202432.tgz' [part 299, 15MB]
15728640 of 15728640 100% in 1s 8.45 MB/s done

upload: '' -> 's3://yetest/backups/si106-251/si106-251.20221219202432.tgz' [part 299, 15MB]
15728640 of 15728640 100% in 1s 8.45 MB/s done <------ 8.45MB/s

Comment: Is your NFS accessed over the Internet?

Comment: @AnonCoward  NFS is storage mounted as a drive on UNIX host with a 10gbps pipe to datacenter

Comment: So, you appear to be comparing a connecting to a datacenter to internet speeds.  Have you tried using the AWS CLI along with [updating the various S3 options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html)?

Comment: @AnonCoward  yes I have ... playing around with bandwidth etc  ie up to 200Mb/s but I only see it peaks out at ~30mb/s - NOTE this is always a LARGE backup tar file I trying to store hence I can not split the file up to multiple uploads ...

  max_concurrent_requests = 20
  max_queue_size = 10000
  multipart_threshold = 64MB
  multipart_chunksize = 16MB
  max_bandwidth = 200MB/s
  use_accelerate_endpoint = true
  addressing_style = path

TEST upload a 1gb file

upload: '/root/test1.img' -> 's3:   in    0s    27.57 MB/s  done